# How to completely disable metacontacts support in Empathy?

Tags: empathy, contacts

I've just googled, but I've found nothing, so... How to disable metacontacts at all? I don't want to use this feature.

Thanks.

Comment: are the metacontacts you are referring to, the ability to link multiple account contacts from the same person?

Comment: @mwm, yes, they are.

Comment: as i understand. metacontacts, as you confirmed, are just a way to aggregate multiple contacts from the same person. so to disable them is just the same as not using them, aka, not linking contacts. makes sense?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you don't just ignore this feature? Does it make metacontacts for you without asking you?

Comment: @Chriskin, Empathy makes metacontacts without asking me and it is impossible to split these self-made metacontacts.

Comment: @mwm, yes, but, as I said, it's not impossible not to use metacontacts: Empathy aggregates contacts itself.

Comment: hmm. how does it aggregate? based on what, email, nickname?

Comment: @mwm, Empathy at least aggregates the same contact in two my accounts. It seems that it does this by JID and/or nickname - I'm not sure. This makes me guess from what account am I writing at moment.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Empathy should not be automatically doing this (it sure doesn't for me and I have quite a few candidates for metacontacts). You should report a bug on Empathy's launchpad page or on their upstream bug tracker, as this is surely not normal behaviour (and if it is, it's inconsistent).